# Show more power plans available after clicking battery icon in system tray

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management

I'm using pretty powerful laptops since... forever. I used to switch my power plans a lot to deal with battery energy, heat and fan levels. I was using ThinkPads before they became just ordinary bad designed laptops. Now I'm using Dell Precision and I'm missing IBM/Lenovo Power Manager software, where I could just press hotkey and click desired power plan.

Without my precious IBM/Lenovo Power Manager software I have to use native Windows power management.

**Windows power management shows only 2 power plans when I click battery icon in tray.**

I'm using more than 2 power plans:

- adaptive with low temperature priority
- adaptive with low noise priority
- power saving with low temperature priority
- power saving with low noise

Sometimes I'm switching to Maximum performance mode, but I can live without accessing it with 2 clicks.

I could install something like Power Scheme Switcher, but... it shows too many plans (Dell software adds few plans which I never need, but I can't delete them).

---

**Question:**

Is it possible to force Windows to show more power plans here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how to do exactly what you're asking for, but I have a pretty good alternative. You can make custom shortcuts, omitting the need for using the mouse at all. The shortcuts I'm talking about would immediately set the setting to whichever you made the shortcut for. You can make shortcuts for all the power plans.

Open cmd.exe and type:

```
powercfg -list
```

This lists all the possible power plans. Lets say we want to change to the Maximum performance scheme. The output for this plan is (for my laptop, it might be slightly different for yours):
`Power Scheme GUID: 7a405782-fa87-40fe-b604-170b49caba1a  (Maximum Performance)` To then change to this power plan, you can type (7a405.... with the Power Scheme GUID you're laptop lists:

```
powercfg /setactive 7a405782-fa87-40fe-b604-170b49caba1a
```

This will set the powerplan to active.

To create a shortcut, go to "My documents", right-click, new -> shortcut. You will get a create shortcut screen. At type the location of the item, directly fill in the command as stated above. Name the shortcut and finish.

Then right click the shortcut and at the tab shortcut you will find the entry shortcut key. Enter your preferred shortcut there. Windows has some issues with this, so it is best to stick to the Crtl+Alt+xxx syntax. The shortcut should work after you restart the computer.

Of course you can also just click the shortcut, place it on your desktop or in your taskbar.

Comment: Shorcuts with hotkeys created like this are global or I have to open directory?

Comment: They are global. Only there are only a few directories from which they work. For instance if the shortcut is on the desktop it will work, but not if it's somewhere on your data drive.